# load .emacs from url

Tags: emacs

I guess the real quesion is : **how to evaluate a file via it's url**?

Of course it wouldn't be the actual .emacs file, but it it would serve that purpose, so you can run your personal settings on any PC that has emacs installed.

I'm aware of the fact that loading a buffer in certain situations (mainly 'toggling stuff) is not the same as evaluating a buffer afterwards, but that's OK.

Comment: If you're using ZSH, you can use something like `emacs -q -l =(curl http://url/to/some/file)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`browse-url-emacs` from the standard `url` library makes this simple. It displays the resulting buffer, which you probably don't want in this case, but we can wrap it with `save-window-excursion` to circumvent that issue.

```el
(save-window-excursion
  (eval-buffer (browse-url-emacs "http://foo/bar.el")))
```

or with some rudimentary error handling:

```el
(condition-case e
    (save-window-excursion
      (eval-buffer
       (browse-url-emacs "http://foo/bar.el")))
  (error (message "Could not load remote library: %s" (cadr e))))
```

Comment: Nice, just tested it successfully.

Answer (score 1):

`(url-handler-mode 1)` after which you can `(load "http://foo/bar/baz")`.

I recommend you don't do that, tho, since you're exposing yourself to some serious security hole if you do that (e.g., an intermediary could substitute the file with another one that sends a nasty email to your boss/husband/...).  It also come with a bunch of other annoying side-effects such as "slow start" or "hangs at startup when the remote server is unreachable", ...
What I do instead is to keep my .emacs in a Bazaar repository sync'd with some remote repository.

Comment: It's more about loading it after startup, and my remote file is quite safe.  Probably not unsafer then the remote repository you are using.

Comment: The risk is not that someone hacks into the remote server, but that someone captures the packets and changes them on the fly.  In contrast, my remote repository is accessed over ssh, so this risk is avoided.

Comment: Ok, my is 'only' ssl, still, hacking that?  I think I'll take my chances.  I'm not a bank after all..