# Open remote Server Files in local emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs23

I used to be a comfortable emacs user and for close to 10 years I completely got away from using emacs (I know its a shame) but I have a wage memory of setting something in `.emacs` to open remote files in a server via local emacs.

Just to make the scenario clear: 
Login to a remote server (ssh) -> emacs somefileInRemoreServer.file &
File get open using the local version of emacs.

My questions are:

1. Is this possible?
2. how can I accomplish this?

I have both mac and ubuntu on mac I use [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/). It would be a great help if I can get instructions on both versions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a single emacs instance from multiple (virtual) machines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154224/using-a-single-emacs-instance-from-multiple-virtual-machines) and [Originate edit of remote file using emacs tramp from ssh session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231902/originate-edit-of-remote-file-using-emacs-tramp-from-ssh-session) and http://snarfed.org/emacsclient_in_tramp_remote_shells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you want to ssh prior to using emacs or ssh using (in) emacs.
If you want to let emacs do all the work check out the links added by phils, TRAMP mode is the way to go for remote editing IN emacs.
If you want to use ssh to mount a remote filesystem (resulting in "local" editing with emacs) you should check out sshfs ([man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs), [wiki](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/FUSE/sshfs)).
I think it comes with pretty much any  of the current distros (or can be installed easily otherwise). It is a fuse extension which allows to mount a remote directory to a local one without any further requirements on the remote side than ssh.
I do like TRAMP for editing one or two files but using sshfs is great for working on a whole project directory which is placed remotely and which you do not want to sync using another method.