# Is it possible to open a file on an ubuntu server with a local text editor?

Tags: ubuntu, text-editor, vi

I have to edit a lot of files on my Ubuntu server. Filezilla sometimes blocks them from being loaded or pushed up with my changes. I was wondering if it is possible for me to access a file through the command line similar to

```
vi myTextFile.txt
```

But instead of using the cmd window it opens up sublime text 2 or some other text editor. Can this be done? or is it rather complex or not even possible?

Comment: Emacs does this easily out of the box, but your question is tagged `vi`.

Comment: I tagged as Vi because its the default and is related in a way. but if it shouldn't be there feel free to remove

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546722/using-emacs-server-and-emacsclient-on-other-machines-as-other-users for what appears to be your primary use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a perfect reason for using GNU Emacs. There is the excellent preinstalled [trampmode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode).  You can easily use GNU Emacs from your local machine in terminal mode using `emacs -nw` („no window“).

Then you can open a remote file like /ssh:user@remotehost:filename

What happens next: You edit the file on your local machine, every time you save it, it is updated - behind the scenes - to your server.

Once you are logged in with GNU Emacs, you can easily hop from one file to the other without reentering your password. You can even go to `dired` and thus have a very powerful file system utility.

Last but not last, since you are obviously coming from a vi-background: There is GNU Emacs `evil-mode` which makes GNU Emacs behave like vi(m).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a remote file via Vim, you can do it this way:

`vim scp://remoteuser@server.tld//path/to/document`

Comment: yeah I've been doing that but I find it tedious for large files and was hoping it could be accessed via a local text editor without the download process